# Optimizing XML import in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have this code to import a XML with 50mb, that contains around 26.280 entities.
But this is taking to long, is with 50 minutes and still running, is that ok? or this code can be optimizing ?

```
INSERT INTO OSUSR_DFP_PEP_ENTITIES (ENT_ID, NAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PREFIX, SUFFIX,
                      AKA, NAMESOURCE, PARENTID, GOVDESIGNATION, ENTRYTYPE, ENTRYCATEGORY, ENTRYSUBCATEGORY,
                      ORGANIZATION, POSITIONS, REMARKS, DOB, POB, COUNTRY, EXPIRATIONDATE, EFFECTIVEDATE, 
                      PICTUREFILE, LINKEDTO, RELATED_ID, SOURCEWEBLINK, TOUCHDATE, DIRECTID, PASSPORTID, 
                      NATIONALID, OTHERID, DOB2, ENTLEVEL, MASTERID, WATCH, RELATIONSHIPS) 
SELECT X.product.query('Ent_ID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.product.query('Name').value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)'),
       X.product.query('FirstName').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('LastName').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Prefix').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Suffix').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.query('Aka').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('NameSource').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('ParentID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.product.query('GovDesignation').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('EntryType').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('EntryCategory').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('EntrySubCategory').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.query('Organization').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Positions').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Remarks').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       X.product.query('DOB').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('POB').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Country').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('ExpirationDate').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('EffectiveDate').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.query('PictureFile').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('LinkedTo').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('Related_ID').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.product.query('SourceWebLink').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       X.product.query('TouchDate').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('DirectID').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('PassportID').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.query('NationalID').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('OtherID').value('.', 'nvarchar(50)'),
       X.product.query('DOB2').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('EntLevel').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.query('MasterID').value('.', 'int'),
       X.product.query('Watch').value('.', 'bit'),
       X.product.query('Relationships').value('.', 'bit')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\temp\teste.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
     ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Export/Entities') AS X(product);
```

--- Working version, only takes 42 seconds

```
DECLARE @X XML

SELECT @X = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\temp\teste.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)


INSERT INTO OSUSR_DFP_PEP_ENTITIES (ENT_ID, NAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PREFIX, SUFFIX,
                      AKA, NAMESOURCE, PARENTID, GOVDESIGNATION, ENTRYTYPE, ENTRYCATEGORY, ENTRYSUBCATEGORY,
                      ORGANIZATION, POSITIONS, REMARKS, DOB, POB, COUNTRY, EXPIRATIONDATE, EFFECTIVEDATE, 
                      PICTUREFILE, LINKEDTO, RELATED_ID, SOURCEWEBLINK, TOUCHDATE, DIRECTID, PASSPORTID, 
                      NATIONALID, OTHERID, DOB2, ENTLEVEL, MASTERID, WATCH, RELATIONSHIPS) 
SELECT X.product.value('(Ent_ID/text())[1]', 'INT'),
       X.product.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)'),
       X.product.value('(FirstName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(LastName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Prefix/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Suffix/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.value('(Aka/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(NameSource/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(ParentID/text())[1]', 'INT'),
       X.product.value('(GovDesignation/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(EntryType/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(EntryCategory/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(EntrySubCategory/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.value('(Organization/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Positions/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Remarks/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       X.product.value('(DOB/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(POB/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Country/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(ExpirationDate/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(EffectiveDate/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.value('(PictureFile/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(LinkedTo/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(Related_ID/text())[1]', 'INT'),
       X.product.value('(SourceWebLink/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       X.product.value('(TouchDate/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(DirectID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(PassportID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),

       X.product.value('(NationalID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(OtherID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
       X.product.value('(DOB2/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(EntLevel/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)'),
       X.product.value('(MasterID/text())[1]', 'INT'),
       X.product.value('(Watch/text())[1]'), 'bit',
       X.product.value('(Relationships/text())[1]', 'bit')

FROM @X.nodes('Export/Entities') AS X(product);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest two things.

1. Load the XML to a XML variable and use the XML variable in the query.
2. Change the code where you extract the values to only use `.value` and use `text()`.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @X XML

SELECT @X = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\temp\teste.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

INSERT INTO OSUSR_DFP_PEP_ENTITIES
.
.
.
SELECT X.product.value('(Ent_ID/text())[1]'), 'INT'),
       X.product.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)'),
.
.
.
FROM @X.nodes('Export/Entities') AS X(product);
```

Comment: just add a new version in my post with your sugestion, but is giving me this error; The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
The slect and insert have the same columms

Comment: was a ')' extra in some lines. its works. only takes 42 seconds

Comment: Loading a 50MB xml file into a variable might use up something like 8x times the memory (thanks MSXML). Suppose this was a 2GB XML file...

Comment: Might someone elaborate on why `/text()` is desirable? At least for my current XML files, it seems to work without that suffix. Is there any performance gain in such a situation? I'm happy to type it if it has a benefit, but if it's the same, I'd like to streamline my code by removing it.

Comment: @underscore_d it is for performance reasons. It is also symanticly different if you deal with mixed content XML. Not sure there is an answer here that elaborates on how it works. Ask a new question if you want more specifics on what is different in the query plan, what makes it faster.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I need to benchmark large queries with and without the suffix. I did anticipate that it might be necessary for XML tags that contain attributes in addition to inner text. I'll search some more. :)